# Solving VBA Run time 91 error

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to enter value into a website's input field using Excel VBA:

```
Dim FileN As Object
Set FileN = ie.document.getElementsByName("MsgNamePattern")
MsgBox (FileN)
If Not FileN Is Nothing And FileN.Length > 0 Then
        FileN(0).Value = fileName
End If
```

Here is the html code for the input field

```
<input name="MsgNamePattern" onblur="validateMessageName(this)" type="text" size="20">
```

I made a MsgBox for debugging that is supposed to say "object HTMLinputelement" if it successfully set the object, but I keep getting the run-time 91 error that the object variable is not set for some reason. I logged into the site successfully with the following code:

```
Dim UserN As Object
Set UserN = ie.document.getElementsByName("userid")
    MsgBox (UserN)
    If Not UserN Is Nothing And UserN.Length > 0 Then
        UserN(0).Value = "username"
    End If
```

And the MsgBox would return "object HTMLinputelement". Here is the HTML for the log in input field:

```
<input name="userid" class="inputStyle" onchange="document.login.password.focus();" type="text" size="20">
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, I thought I used the same method to log in successfully, so I'm confused why it's not working for a search field after logging in.

---

Here's the entire code:

```
Sub getComponents()

   Dim WebAddressIn As String
   Dim ie As Object
   Set ie = New InternetExplorer
   WebAddressIn = "https://edx.standardandpoors.com/mailbox/jsp/login.jsp"

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Navigate2 WebAddressIn

    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Visible = True

    Dim UserN As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim PW As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ElementCol As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    ' enter username and password in textboxes
    Set UserN = ie.document.getElementsByName("userid")
    MsgBox UserN
    If Not UserN Is Nothing And UserN.Length > 0 Then
        ' fill in first element named "username", assumed to be the login name field
        UserN(0).Value = "username"
    End If

    Set PW = ie.document.getElementsByName("password")
    ' password
    If Not PW Is Nothing And PW.Length > 0 Then
        ' fill in first element named "password", assumed to be the password field
        PW(0).Value = "password"
    End If

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Set ElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByName("submit")
    MsgBox ElementCol
    For Each btnInput In ElementCol
        If btnInput.Value = "*Sign In" Then
            btnInput.Click
           Exit For
        End If
    Next btnInput

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
    Loop

     Dim fileName As String
     fileName = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd") & "_SPGSCI_PRE_STD.TXT"

    Dim FileN As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim SearchBox As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Visible = True

    'Modified to add Tehscript's edit
    'Set FileN = ie.document.getElementsByName("MsgNamePattern")
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FileN = ie.document.getElementsByName("MsgNamePattern")(0)
    Loop Until Err.Number <> 91

    MsgBox FileN
    If Not FileN Is Nothing And FileN.Length > 0 Then
        FileN(0).Value = fileName
    End If

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Set SearchBox = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each l In SearchBox
        If l.href = "javascript:myFunction('/mailbox/jsp/MBIList.jsp')" Then
            l.Click
    Exit For
        End If
    Next l

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Not related to your problem (which I assume is happening on the `Set` line) but `If Not UserN Is Nothing And UserN.Length > 0 Then` will crash if `UserN` is `Nothing` - because `Nothing` won't have a `Length` property.

Comment: Is `ie.document` set? FWIW unless the `UserN` object has a *default property* that returns [something representable as] a string, that `MsgBox` call is going to blow up too: remove the parentheses, they're forcing the parameter to be evaluated and passed as a value.. should be `MsgBox UserN.Value`.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I edited the MsgBox but it didn't seem to change anything (still outputted object...) How do I make sure ie.document is set? I also added my entire code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your code, after navigating to the url.

```
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
    DoEvents
Loop
```

If you still have "run-time error 91" then replace

```
Set UserN = ie.document.getElementsByName("userid")
```

with the following:

```
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set UserN = ie.document.getElementsByName("userid")
Loop Until Err.Number <> 91
```

Comment: My error was with FileN no UserN but I tried replacing the line and the MsgBox doesn't even popup. The input field still stays empty on the site as my code never enters the If Not FileN... loop

Comment: I changed "UserN" to "FileN" and "userid" to "MsgNamePattern" in your code because that's the part of the code with the Run time error, but the MsgBox does not popup and when I F8 through to debug, I see that it's still not entering the "If Not FileN Is Nothing..." loop

Comment: @user90823745 There is nothing I can do unless you share the html or the url because it works with a random website I have tested.

Comment: I showed that as an example of my code that works for UserN and how I tried the same method for FileN but failed. The HTML code for "MsgNamePattern" is the 2nd block of code in my original question post

Comment: @user90823745 Try `Set FileN = ie.document.getElementsByName("MsgNamePattern")(0)`

Comment: I don't get the error 91 anymore but the message box still doesn't populate with my search :(

Comment: @user90823745 Can you share the website? Without looking at the whole picture, it is unlikely to guess what is wrong with your code. This might be because there are more than one elements having the same name, and we are trying to scrape the wrong one. I hope my example explains the issue.